# Dictionary and KeyValuePair

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a new program in which I have a list of dates and corresponding signs. for example:

```
DateTime AriasStart = new DateTime(birthDay.Year, 3, 21);
DateTime AriasEnd = new DateTime(birthDay.Year, 4, 20);
```

I would like to create a dictionary for a sign and then the corresponding start and end date. What would be the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) as the second generic type of the dictionary:

```
var zodiac = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>>();

DateTime ariasStart = new DateTime(birthDay.Year, 3, 21);
DateTime ariasEnd = new DateTime(birthDay.Year, 4, 20);
var ariasStartEnd = new Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>(ariasStart, ariasEnd);

zodiac.Add("Arias", ariasStartEnd);
```

Another option, which will be more meaningful, is to write your own class for zodiac signs that contains the names and dates and use that in a list/dictionary.